# How to fix splash screen for Android?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I'm using Expo on a React Native app (react 0.59 and SDK 32), and the splash screen on Android shows a white bar at the top of the screen, like it's not a full screen.
The splash images have a background color #CEECFF.

How could I avoid it?

Here is my app.json:

```
"expo": {
    ...
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/common/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#CEECFF"
    },
    "android": {
      ...
      "splash": {
        "backgroundColor": "#CEECFF",
        "resizeMode": "contain",
        "mdpi": "./assets/images/common/splash-mdpi.png",
        "hdpi": "./assets/images/common/splash-hdpi.png",
        "xhdpi": "./assets/images/common/splash-xhdpi.png",
        "xxhdpi": "./assets/images/common/splash-xxhdpi.png",
        "xxxhdpi": "./assets/images/common/splash-xxxhdpi.png"
      }
    }
  }
```

Thank you very much!

EDIT: looks like a behavior specific to EXPO CLI, works fine once the app is build with EXPO and tested as native on Android...

Comment: try to change resize mode to cover  `"resizeMode": "cover"`

Comment: Tried that as well with the same effect :(

Answer (score 1):

change resizeMode to "cover"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Please add these properties  to remove white bar at the top of screen.

```
 "androidStatusBar": {
      "backgroundColor": "#C2185B"
    }
```

or You can hide status bar.Please check this:-
https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/guides/configuring-statusbar/